# Changing domain mapping on Mac OSX etc/hosts to Vagrant Virtual Machine

Tags: macos, hosting, vagrantfile, domain-mapping

I've been trying to change the mapping for a domain and forward it to a Vagrant machine that I've forwarded a port to.

The config in Vagrantfile:

`Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
       config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
   end`

I've updated /etc/hosts on my Mac OSX with the following:

`127.0.0.1:4567    example.com`

Yet when I access from my browser example.com nothing changes, I have also tried to map example.com to go to the Google IP without any luck.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just add a static ip, or try removing the port number:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

Then in your hosts file change it to read:

```
192.168.50.4 example.com
```

More info is available here:
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html

Comment: Works like a charm - still curious about the way I was setting up my etc/hosts. When I ssh into the vagrant box and run ifconfig I see in the 'inet' an IP address -- I used that too without luck. Seems like I'm missing the correct IP address to use when I forward a port.